# Some issues about Uniform Distibution in Inverse Transform Method

Tags: mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

There is a theorem about inverse transform method says if X is a continuous random variable with cdf F, then U=F(X)~U[0,1]

So I am wondering the logic in this sentence. 
Why if X is a continuous random variable with cdf F, then U=F(X)~U[0,1]?
Why is it always be uniform and 
how does this theorem work in real example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fundamental fact follows directly from the *definition* of a cumulative density function (CDF), after applying some clever manipulation.

The *definition* of the CDF is the following

> A function $F$ is called the CDF of a random variable $X$ when, for every number $z$, $P(X < z) = F(z)$.

Now, if we are in the above situation, we can ask

> What is the CDF of the random variable $F(X)$?

Let's see

$$P(F(X) < z) = P(F^{-1}(F(X)) < F^{-1}(z)) = P(X < F^{-1}(z)) = F(F^{-1}(z)) = z $$

Here:

- In the first equality I have used that a CDF is always an increasing function.  Otherwise there would be no (or a much more complex) relation between the two probabilities.
- In the second to last equality I have used the *definition* of a CDF, applied to the fact that $F$ is the CDF of the random variable $X$.

Reading from top to bottom:

$$P(F(X) < z) = z $$

Which, comparing with the definition of a CDF again, shows that the CDF of $F(X)$ is the identity function.  The identity function is *also* the CDF of the uniform distribution.  Distributions are the same if and only if their CDF is the same, so this also means that

$$ F(X) \sim U(0, 1) $$

Comment: This seems like a really interesting result and I finally figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @BrattSwan It's a classic.

Comment: However, suppose I have a pdf f=3*x^2, the the cdf of f, which is F=x^3, the cdf of F, which is 0.25*x^4, which is not a identity function. Is there anything I misunderstood?